# Excel arrow buttons to scroll through TABS don't work

Tags: excel, scroll, tabs

I have a workbook in which the 2 little left and right arrows at the bottom left which we use to move through tabs are not working. I can still right-click and choose the tab I want to go to, but I'm baffled as to why the arrows themselves no longer work. And the left arrow is always greyed out even if I've navigated to the rightmost tab. And if I do navigate to the rightmost tab, I don't see the tab name at the bottom of my screen; it remains hidden behind the scroll bar. The right arrow is always dark/black and seems like it should be working. Any idea why that might happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ctrl + Pageup or Pagedown, hopefully that helps you until someone can answer or assist on the real issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and I resolved it by clicking the vertical 3 dots on the far right and then sliding it to the far right and then clicked on the "+" just to the left of it which added a new sheet and then clicked on the horizonal "..." I then deleted that new sheet that I added and voila, now I can scroll left and right using the left and right arrows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nlpH.png)

Comment: Thank you Julie. I actually can't find that workbook right now but I'll keep your answer for when it comes up again. Thanks!